# How to fix error "TypeError: client.click is not a function" when testing android application by Appium?

Tags: javascript, appium-android

I have installed software for make automate test my android application on Windows 10(64): Android SDK, JDK, Appium Client for Windows, nodeJS.
Set system variables(Home...), set virtual device(genimotion-android-v.8.0.0),configure and start Appium - I see my application and can get UI-elements.

*That output from Appium Doctor:*

```
info AppiumDoctor Appium Doctor v.1.8.0
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic for necessary dependencies starting ###
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Node.js binary was found at: D:\-inst\nodejs\node.EXE
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Node version is 10.15.0
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ ANDROID_HOME is set to: D:\-inst\-SDKAndroid\Sdk
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ JAVA_HOME is set to: D:\-inst\JavaSDK\jdk1.8.0_181
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ adb exists at: D:\-inst\-SDKAndroid\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ android exists at: D:\-inst\-SDKAndroid\Sdk\tools\android.bat
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ emulator exists at: D:\-inst\-SDKAndroid\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Bin directory of %JAVA_HOME% is set
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic for necessary dependencies completed, no fix needed. ###
info AppiumDoctor
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic for optional dependencies starting ###
WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ opencv4nodejs cannot be found.
WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ ffmpeg cannot be found
WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ bundletool.jar cannot be found
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic for optional dependencies completed, 3 fixes needed. ###
info AppiumDoctor
info AppiumDoctor ### Optional Manual Fixes ###
info AppiumDoctor The configuration can install optionally. Please do the following manually:
WARN AppiumDoctor  ➜ Why opencv4nodejs is needed and how to install it: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/image-comparison.md
WARN AppiumDoctor  ➜ ffmpeg is needed to record screen features. Please read https://www.ffmpeg.org/ to install it
WARN AppiumDoctor  ➜ bundletool.jar is used to handle Android App Bundle. Please read http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-appbundle/ to install it
info AppiumDoctor
info AppiumDoctor ###
info AppiumDoctor
info AppiumDoctor Bye! Run appium-doctor again when all manual fixes have been applied!
```

*next I installed*:    appium-uiautomator2-driver  mocha chai chai-as-promised
 wd  wdio-appium-service  webdriverio  wdio-mocha-framework.

*There is my config file:*

```
configure:

exports.options = {

capabilities: {

        platformName: 'Android',

        platformVersion:'8.0.0',

        appPackage:'com.alex89607.filelist',

        appActivity:'com.alex89607.filelist.MainActivity',

        automationName: 'UiAutomator2',


            deviceName: '192.168.160.101:5555',
    app: 'e:\\app-debug.apk'

    },

  host: 'localhost',

  port: 4723

};
```

I use following instruction:
 [a Beginners Guide to Using Appium with NodeJs for Automation Testing of Android Applications](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/appium-with-nodejs-for-automation-testing-of-android-applications/)

I try to use another virtual android device whith the same result.

*There is my test code:*

```js
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var config = require('./helpers/desiredCapabilities').options;
var client = webdriverio.remote(config);

describe('CALCU Testing', function() {

  before(function() {
    this.timeout(50000);
    return client.init();
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    this.timeout(5000);
    return client.click('android=new UiSelector().resourceId("com.alex89607.filelist:id/clear")');
  });
});


//addition testing
describe("Test CALCU addition", function() {

  this.timeout(55000);

  it("test-close-startup-screen", function() {
    return client.click('android=new UiSelector().resourceId("com.alex89607.filelist:id/clear")');
  });

});
```

I expect pass my test, but I get:

> test-close-startup-screen:
>        TypeError: `client.click` is not a function.

edit:
Appium 1.10.0
node -v v10.15.0
npm -v 6.4.1

all error message:
        e:-curr\190121.nodeJS\1.test\CALCU node.js android test>npm run webdriverio-calcu

```
> test@1.0.0 webdriverio-calcu e:\-curr\190121.nodeJS\1.test\CALCU node.js android test
> mocha webdriverio-calcu.js

2019-01-24T07:44:28.250Z DEBUG wdio-config: @wdio/sync not found, running tests asynchronous
2019-01-24T07:44:28.589Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub/session
2019-01-24T07:44:28.592Z INFO webdriver: DATA { capabilities:
   { alwaysMatch:
      { platformName: 'Android',
        platformVersion: '8.0.0',
        appPackage: 'com.alex89607.filelist',
        appActivity: 'com.alex89607.filelist.MainActivity',
        automationName: 'UiAutomator2',
        deviceName: '192.168.160.101:5555',
        app: 'e:\\app-debug.apk' },
     firstMatch: [ {} ] },
  desiredCapabilities:
   { platformName: 'Android',
     platformVersion: '8.0.0',
     appPackage: 'com.alex89607.filelist',
     appActivity: 'com.alex89607.filelist.MainActivity',
     automationName: 'UiAutomator2',
     deviceName: '192.168.160.101:5555',
     app: 'e:\\app-debug.apk' } }


  Test CALCU addition
    1) test-close-startup-screen


  0 passing (24ms)
  1 failing

  1) Test CALCU addition
       test-close-startup-screen:
     TypeError: client.click is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (webdriverio-calcu.js:24:27)
      at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:120:23)



npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test@1.0.0 webdriverio-calcu: `mocha webdriverio-calcu.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test@1.0.0 webdriverio-calcu script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\briza\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-24T07_44_37_533Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I'm also facing the same thing...

Comment: Unfortunately, need to switch another urgent task.

Comment: Now I returned at same task and recreated testing enviroment. Finally I used Appium, Java, Eclipse and TestNG for testing Android application. I use following instruction: [APPIUM Tutorial for Android & iOS Mobile Apps Testing.](https://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-appium.html) Its works!